# Is it possible to include a MapView as an element of another activity?

Tags: java, android, google-maps

Just as the title says...I want to include a `MapView` inside of another activity. For instance, I want the `MapView` to take up half of the screen, and below that, include some other widgets - text fields, buttons, whatever. I have been tinkering with it, but so far I have been unsuccessful - the map does take up only half the screen, but no widgets show up.

Any clues? Is this possible, or is the Google `Map` integration strictly using the map as a full screen?

Comment: Just a guess but you're using a `LinearLayout` to contain the `MapView` and other widgets but you forgot to set the orientation to vertical? The default for `LinearLayout` is horizontal.

Comment: You're right...answer instead of comment, and I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: and the answer 1 hour ago this comment is not correct?

Comment: @Profete162: Although you gave a working example, it didn't explain why Doctor Oreo's approach wasn't working. My 'lucky guess' at least serves as a learning exercise - having made the same mistake myself a few times, I now always remember to explicitly set the orientation of any `LinearLayout` I use. It's up to Doctor Oreo to choose which answer helped most in this situation.

Comment: @Profete162, MisterSquonk is correct. Both of your answers were very useful, but MisterSquonk hit the nail on the head - I didn't realize the default orientation was horizontal. I have +1 each of your posts, because as I said, they were both helpful. You put in the effort to post an example, which I appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a guess but you're using a `LinearLayout` to contain the `MapView` and other widgets but you forgot to set the orientation to vertical? The default for `LinearLayout` is horizontal.

It came to mind because it's something I've done 2 or 3 times myself. Totally confusing as effectively the other widgets 'disappear' off the right-hand side of the screen. It eventually got engrained in my mind and I always make sure to explicitly specify orientation now when I use `LinearLayout`.

Answer (score 3):

Please post your xml layout!
You are just doing it wrong. :-D

A mapview will work like any other widget. I strongly believe there is a mistake in your layout.

This one will work for instance!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/h1"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <CheckBox 
         android:text="Satellite" 
         android:id="@+id/satellite" 
         android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
         android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </CheckBox>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="75dip"
        android:layout_height="75dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
        android:src="@drawable/uoicon" />
  </LinearLayout>

  <com.google.android.maps.MapView
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@+id/mapview"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:clickable="true"
      android:apiKey="0zDdYFYf6Ir2W-NuiHPLAoFjsq0nmqRhPfzjY3A"/>


</LinearLayout>
```